# solve the 3 simultaneous equations with 3 unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

This is the system I need to solve :

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> 10-14x+8y+5z=0 \\
> 10-x-2y-6z=0 \\
> 10-9x+12y-2z=0 \\
> \end{cases}
> $$

How do I solve for all three?

Any help would be of great help. But I need step by step instructions for each unknown. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It doesn't work this way. You need to show some effort as to how you would try to solve this. Otherwise it "looks" like we are doing the homework. What method(s) have you encountered in your class to solve 3 by 3's ?

Comment: Solve (1) for $x$ and use in (2) and (3). Solve the new (2) for $y$ and use in (3), finally solve (3) for $z$. Now back solve for $y$ and $x$.

Comment: How would you solve a system of two equations in two unknowns? It’s the same for a larger system. It just takes more steps to get to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

wrting your system in the form
$$-x-2y-6z=-10$$
$$-9x+12y-2z=-10$$
$$-14x+8y+5z=-10$$
then we get
multiplying the first equation by $-9$ and adding to the second :
$$30y+52z=80$$
and multiplying the first by $-14$ and adding to the third:
$$36y+89z=130$$
can you do the last steps?

Answer (score 1):

Well you should try eliminating x from the first and second equations by multiplying them with a suitable integer and then adding or subtracting the two equations as required to eliminate x. This would give you an equation in y and z. Then do the same with the second and third equations to eliminate x. Now you two simultaneous equations in y and z . Solve them by substitution of any other method for your choice to obtain the values of y and z. Then put this value in any one of the three equations to find the value of X. You will get the answer!

Comment: Well I have answered your query . If you are satisfied you can accept the answer